# Why I am getting "Apple Mach -O Linker error"?

Tags: objective-c

I have two UIViewControllers. They have two variables with the same names but in different files.

HomeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

HomeViewController.m

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController
bool search=true;
bool dbOpen=false;

....

@end
```

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
bool search=true;
bool dbOpen=false;

....

@end
```

When I remove "search" and "dbOpen" variables from HomeViewController.m or DetailViewController.m files, it compiles successfully. Why this is happening? Variables are not in header files and m files don't know about each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables (what you have) are global, it doesn't matter if they are in different files (also what makes them dangerous).

```
bool search;
```

A global can only be defined once or you will get a linker error. Also people will avoid you at social events.

Static variables are per file - this might have been what you meant..

```
static bool search;
```

Instance variables are per instance. This is probably what you meant. You should start by using Properties - the compiler will handle adding the instance variable that backs it.
Something along the lines of:

```
@property bool search;
```

I'm trusting that you mean to use bool and not the Objective-c type BOOL. Visibility is up to you. Define the property in the Interface if you want it to be public.

If you really don't want a property you should define your instance variables in the interface section.

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {
  bool search;
}
@end
```

Just to make it more confusing.. If you really must define the Instance variables in the Implementation there is a way, but I can't bring myself to type it.

Answer (score 0):

This is classical error of using global variables. Try to avoid to use it. In general use the `extern` keyword.

> You use extern with global variables to create unambiguous
>   declarations. In addition to helping the compiler, it also clues in
>   anyone reading the code that the global variable is defined (and
>   possibly initialized) elsewhere, but you're simply using it here

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
extern bool search=true;
extern bool dbOpen=false;

....

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable declarations have to be in the `@interface` like:

```
@interface HomeViewController ()
    BOOL search;
    BOOL dbOpen;
@end
```

and

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
    BOOL search;
    BOOL dbOpen;
@end
```

To set their initial values add the assignment in for exam,e `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    search = YES;
    dbOpen = NO;
}
```

Note the other changes like `BOOL` and YES/NO.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared these variables

```
bool search=true;
bool dbOpen=false;
```

as global, only one occurance of these variables can exist. Change the name of the global variables in `"HomeViewController.m"` or  `"DetailViewController.m"`